# Laravel : How to use a parameters in a Form POST to be use in a Route::post?

Tags: php, html, laravel

This my current POST route.

`Route::post('/eAPI', 'ApiController@eAPI');`

I wanted to make it like

`Route::post('/q={$number}', 'ApiController@eAPI');`

But in my form.

```html
<form action="{{url('/eAPI')}}" method="post" id="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="number" class="col-md-4 control-label">Telephone Number to search :</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Phone (eg. 5551234567)" required>


    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="submit" name="name" value="Find" class="btn btn-success">
  </div>
</form>
```

Now, I want to put a variable in this part, something like this.

`<form action="{{url('/?q=$number')}}" method="post" id="search">`

Comment: Does it have to append the URL?  Why not just create a hidden field in the form? `<input type="hidden" name="q" value="{{$number}}">`

Answer (score 2):

In post request you should do it like this:

```
Route::post('/eAPI/{q}', 'ApiController@eAPI')->name('my_route');
```

And in HTML Form:

```
<form action="{{ route('my_route', ['q' => '4']) }}" method="post" id="search">
</form>
```

And inside controller you can retrieve it as:

```
Class ApiController {

    public function eAPI($q) {
        // Use $q here ...
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I understood correctly, OP wants to use `?q=value` parameters. If not, it's definitely the right way to pass the data.

Comment: Ya but in case of POST request either he should send that value using form or by the way which I've suggested above!

Comment: But the NUMBER must be dynamic. In your example, '4' is static. Based on my code, <input class="form-control" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Phone (eg. 5551234567)" required> . How do I parse this to use in that route.

Comment: The way you're trying to do it is wrong in my sense, it can only be done by some JS hack and changing the URL according to the entered input

Answer (score 2):

This works for me [method post and url has ?q=someValue] :

```
 public function eApi(Request $request){
     $q = $request['q'];
 }
```

This code will get all params in post and get method

```
$request->all()
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I never did and will never do this with `post` requests, but it works with `get` requests:

```
$q = request()->q;
```

And you don't need to add this to the route: `q={$number}`, just add parameters to url: `?q=value1&s=value2&c=value3`